# stm32f051r8t6 TIM14 interrupt handler not working after reset

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt-handling, stm32f0

I am using STM32CubeMX to generate code into IAR, and I am using a stm32f051r8t6 microcontroller,
The problem I am having is that when first loading the code onto the chip, it all works perfect, however after pressing restart on either the board or IAR debugger, the TIM14 interrupt handler is not entered, but as soon as I leave the debugger and enter again, it starts working until I press restart. Has anybody come across this problem before? My code is below

```
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void);

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == TIM14)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, USART1_TE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
   /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

   /* USER CODE END 1 */

   /* MCU Configuration---------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the
  Systick.    */
  HAL_Init();

 /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

 /* USER CODE END Init */

 /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM14_Init();

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim14);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
 while (1)
{
FslBufferControl();
MimModeCheck();
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void)
{

 /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 1 */

 /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 1 */
 htim14.Instance = TIM14;
 htim14.Init.Prescaler = 47999;
 htim14.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
 htim14.Init.Period = 1;
 htim14.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
 htim14.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
 if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim14) != HAL_OK)
 {
  Error_Handler();
 }
 /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 2 */

 /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 2 */

 }
```

Comment: Sounds more like a debugger problem then an programming issue.

Comment: I thought that too, however when I had the chip running of a power supply and not connected to the PC, the same problem was occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to enable the interrupt.

```
  MX_TIM14_Init();

  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM14_IRQn);   // <----------------------------

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim14);
```

Just check the IRQn TIM14 UG event number. They are defined in the `IRQn_Type` enum type defined in the `STM32F___.h` file where `___` is the model of your micro (you will find it in the include folder)

Comment: Thankyou very much! TIM14 IRQn is 19, so do I need to write 'HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM14_IRQ19)?

Comment: Hi, I have added that line to my code and unfortunately the same thing is happening, on initial load of the debugger it works fine, however after pressing restart it does not enter the 'void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)' function

Comment: `TIM14_IRQn`  ----

Comment: Hi, I have just realised my mistake, as I am using a new IDE (from keil to IAR) I did not realise the debugger was automatically set to 'software reset' not 'hardware rest pin', I have altered this setting and it is now working fine with the debugger and without, thank you for your help